# How to send form param using scala play 2.4.X WSClient

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to send form params using WSClient. My first approach is putting all parameters inside a Map:

```
val params = Map(
  "param1" -> s"${config.param1}",
  "param2" -> s"${config.param2}"
)

ws.url(s"${config.host}").post(params).map { response =>
  response.json.as[MyResponse]

}
```

It this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWS#Submitting-form-data), the entity must be given as a `Map[String, Seq[String]]`.